# Print values adjacent from json file with query

Tags: json, jq

I have below json file

```
    {
  "total": 64,
  "p": 1,
  "ps": 1,
  "paging": {
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 1,
    "total": 64
  },
  "effortTotal": 216,
  "issues": [
    {
      "key": "AX8lZNY1h5xTw2fmJuX6",
      "rule": "xml:S125",
      "severity": "MAJOR",
      "component": "X8lXT9yjCYHsI0QujFF:pom.xml",
      "project": "X8lXT9yjCYHsI0QujFF",
      "line": 29,
      "hash": "6e7405674b46c05cd7d7fc9433dbb323",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 29,
        "endLine": 33,
        "startOffset": 6,
        "endOffset": 22
      },
      "flows": [],
      "status": "OPEN",
      "message": "Remove this commented out code.",
      "effort": "5min",
      "debt": "5min",
      "author": "XXXXXX@XXXXXX.com",
      "tags": [
        "unused"
      ],
      "creationDate": "2021-12-19T18:54:28+0100",
      "updateDate": "2022-02-23T08:03:15+0100",
      "type": "CODE_SMELL",
      "scope": "MAIN"
    }
  ],
  "components": [
    {
      "key": "X8lXT9yjCYHsI0QujFF:pom.xml",
      "enabled": true,
      "qualifier": "FIL",
      "name": "pom.xml",
      "longName": "pom.xml",
      "path": "pom.xml"
    },
    {
      "key": "X8lXT9yjCYHsI0QujFF",
      "enabled": true,
      "qualifier": "TRK",
      "name": "my-app",
      "longName": "my-app"
    }
  ],
  "facets": [
    {
      "property": "types",
      "values": [
        {
          "val": "BUG",
          "count": 34
        },
        {
          "val": "CODE_SMELL",
          "count": 30
        },
        {
          "val": "VULNERABILITY",
          "count": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to print values like below

```
BUG=34
```

I tried below as work around but its not printing as per my requirement

```
jq -r '.facets[].values[0].val,.facets[].values[0].count' file.json
```

which prints like below

```
BUG
34
```

but again I have to mention [0] for BUG [1] for CODE_SMELL so on

is there is any way I can do this so that it should print like below

```
BUG=34
CODE_SMELL:30
VULNERABILITY:0 (it will be null but I can put condition to print it is as zero in shell script while referring it as variable)
```

Please guide  I am newbie to JQ, i know how to do it with sed but it needs more steps to add in script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may extract the `val` and `count` values from each element within the `values` array under `facets` and format them into `key=value` strings like so:

```bash
jq -r '.facets[].values[] | "\(.val)=\(.count // 0 | @sh)"' file
```

The `@sh` operator would ensure that the string was properly formatted to be executed by the shell as variable assignments, quoting strings and escaping potentially problematic characters.

The `.count // 0` will ensure that the value `0` is used whenever `.count` is missing, `null`, or `false`.

Given the document above, this command would produce

```bash
BUG=34
CODE_SMELL=30
VULNERABILITY=0
```

Evaluating the output of the above command would create the shell variables:

```bash
$ unset -v BUG CODE_SMELL VULNERABILITY  # clears the variables
$ eval "$( jq -r '.facets[].values[] | "\(.val)=\(.count // 0 | @sh)"' file )"
$ echo "$BUG"
34
$ printf '%s\n' "$BUG" "$CODE_SMELL" "$VULNERABILITY"
34
30
0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is printing as per your solution but I want to print only for BUG or only for CODE_SMELL , what approach I should use ?

Comment: @Samurai You should specify that in the question, and I will update my answer accordingly as soon as I have time (after meetings this morning).  Currently, the question appears to ask for all variables.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for this confusion, also want to thank you for explanation & helping me to learn jq

Comment: my plan is to extract values as per variable, which can be done using sed but I am not aware how jq works
query will be individual for each variables i.e for BUG or for CODE or VUL

Comment: @Samurai It's still unclear whether you want to extract all, one, or some variables. You could always extract all, `eval` the output (`eval "$( jq ... )"`) and then just use the variable(s) that you need.

Comment: I will use three diff jq commands for BUG= CODE_SMELL= VULNERABILITIES= as below
jq -r '.facets[].values[0].val,.facets[].values[0].count' 
jq -r '.facets[].values[1].val,.facets[].values[1].count'
jq -r '.facets[].values[2].val,.facets[].values[2].count'  But here I have to mention [0][1][2] for respective vaibales, your solution is printing all three at once which also works but then I need to extract values separately , I will check what can be done , Thank you so much for help and support

Comment: @Samurai Just `eval` the output as I showed in my previous comment. This will give you three shell variables with the correct values.

Comment: @Samurai See also updates. I fixed bugs.